# requirejs - returning a object not called by main js file

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am using requirejs, from my main.js - i am calling a method which is been in "header.js", But i am not getting proper response, instead i am getting "undefined"

myMain.js :

```
    requirejs.config({

    baseUrl     : "js",
    paths       : {
        "jquery"    : "lib/jquery-1.9.1.min",
        "jqueryUi"  : "lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min",
        "handleBar" : "lib/handlebars"
    },
    shim            : {

        "handleBar" : {
            exports : 'Handlebars',
            deps:['jquery', 'jqueryUi']
        }
    }

});

require(["jquery","jqueryUi","handleBar","scripts/header"],function (header) {

    console.log(header["getHeader"]);//undefined

});
```

myHeader.js :

```
define(["jquery"],function  ($) {

    var headerHandler = function(){

        return {
            getHeader:function(){
                console.log($); //not getting
                alert("i am getHeader"); //not getting
            }
        }

    }

    return new headerHandler();

})
```

What is wrong here.. is the way i am "returning" - object wrong? if so any one correct me pleae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue at here:

i use this wrongly,

```
require(["jquery","jqueryUi","handleBar","scripts/header"],function (header) {

    console.log(header["getHeader"]);//undefined

});
```

instead of :

```
require(["jquery","jqueryUi", "handleBar", "scripts/header"],function ($,$Ui,hBs,header) {

    header.getHeader();

});
```

Now works fine. thanks all.